# How to get value from input in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get the value from this custom input .So I am passing setter function settypemail in onchange and my expectation is to get the input value in typemail variable when user enters something but I am getting undefined.

Comment: pass the value down aswell? `<CustomInput
    placeholder="Enter your Email Address"
    onChange={settypemail}
    value={typemail}
    style={{ maxWidth: "700px", margin: "30px 0px 20px 0px" }}
/>;`

Comment: Now, the default value  in input is the initial value of hook ie "" and I am not able to type into it

Comment: strage, try taking a look at this demo, maybe it can help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bsj6tu?file=src%2FApp.js  (there was an error with keyPressed not being defined so i deleted it)